# Sort a vector by specific member C++

Tags: c++, class, sorting

Is it possible to sort a `vector` by a specific member of it's class?

I have a class called `Car`:

```
class Carro {
private:
    int positionX;  
    int place;  

public:
    Carro(string marca, float energiaInicial, float energiaMaxima, int velocMax, string model = "modelo base");
    ~Carro();

    void setPosition(int posX);
    void setPlace(int place);

    int getPositionX() const;
    int getPlace() const;};
```

And a vector of cars: `vector<Car*> raceTrack;`

What I want to do is sort this vector according to car's position. If the car A is ahead of car B then A takes 1st place and B takes 2nd place, and so on.

P.S. Imagine that all the cars have already a place defined (ex: car A has 1, car B has 2, car C has 3...)

Comment: Use a custom comparator.

Comment: @Evg how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work (not tested):

```
std::sort(raceTrack.begin(), raceTrack.end(), [](const Carro* a, const Carro* b) {
    return a->getPlace() < b->getPlace();   
});
```